# Getting Error in console while using Formik <ErrorMessage />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik

I'm trying to use Formik with useFormik hook but I'm getting this error in console while using formik . When I remove the  tag the error goes away.
But I don't know how to solve this error:

> Formik context is undefined, please verify you are rendering ,
> , , , or your custom context-using
> component as a child of a  component. Component name:
> ErrorMessageImpl

This is my code:

```
import { ErrorMessage, useFormik } from 'formik';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { useStore } from '../../app/stores/store';

function LoginForm() {
    const { userStore } = useStore();
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            error: null,
        },
        onSubmit: (values, actions) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                userStore.login(values).catch((error) => actions.setErrors({ error: 'Invalid email' }));
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
            }, 500);
        },
    });
    return (
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <div className='input-container'>
                <input
                    id='email'
                    name='email'
                    type='email'
                    placeholder='Email'
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    // values in formik contains initialValues
                    value={formik.values.email}
                />
            </div>
            <div className='input-container'>
                <input
                    id='password'
                    name='password'
                    type='password'
                    placeholder='Password'
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    value={formik.values.password}
                />
            </div>
            <div className='input-container'>
                <ErrorMessage name='error' render={() => <p>{formik.errors}</p>} />
            </div>
            <button type='submit' className='btn btn-secondary'>
                Login
                {formik.isSubmitting && (
                    <span
                        className='spinner-border spinner-border-sm ms-2'
                        role='status'
                        aria-hidden='true'
                    ></span>
                )}
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default observer(LoginForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Formik documentation](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik), you cannot use `<ErrorMessage>` with useFormik.

> ** Be aware that `<Field>`, `<FastField>`, `<ErrorMessage>`, `connect()`, and `<FieldArray>` will NOT work with `useFormik()` as they all require React Context.

Above explains why you're getting the error message re: missing "Formik context"

Answer (score 0):

This error is given because you are not using the context, in other words; You are not indicating where is the form that will use the formik for that you need to put your code between the  formik tags, in your return.

First: Put/change in your import

`import { Form as FormikForm, FormikProvider, useFormik } from "formik";`

Now in your return:

```
return(
      <FormikProvider value={formik}>
         <FormikForm>
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
             <div className='input-container'>
              ......(code).......
         </FormikForm>
      <FormikProvider>
```

Note:

- On import I renamed the Formik Form so as not to create a conflict with the HTML or Bootsratp  (should you use it in the future)
- In the  you are indicating the formik variable, that you created/declared above, inside it you have the initial formik values.